# Netbiscuits, Creating a paragraph tag

Tags: netbiscuits

I'm maintaining a website that is using the Netbiscuits platform. I cannot see how I can actually insert a `<p></p>` tag with BML? Am I missing something here?

I currently have my text in a `<richtext></richtext>` tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out after reading the Official documentation for a while.

```
<richtext>
[p]text here[/p]
[p]more text[/p]
</richtext>
```